# Converting pyspark dataframe to HTML

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to convert a pyspark dataframe to HTML so that I can send it over email using smtplib and MIMEText. Can this be done **without** converting the spark dataframe to pandas(df.topandas().to_html) as we do not have it installed on the server.

```
    DF=spark.sql("select * from table") ## DF needs to be converted to HTML format on pypsark
    
##next steps 
    part1body = MIMEText(DF  , 'html')
    msg.attach(part1body )
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: how about `DF.toPandas().to_html()`

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I need it done on pyspark WITHOUT using pandas.

Comment: @SawanS did you ever get this figured it out?